# Cannot convert value of type 'SKTexture' to expected argument type 'Int'; Error When Use textureNamed("...")

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am following a game tutorial for an iOS app. But there was a version problem, as the tutorial was made with Xcode 8 and swift 3. Im using Xcode 11 and the latest swift version. Anyways, I managed to solve all of the problems that I came across, all accept this one:

```swift
        //setup sprites for animation
        _Sprites.append(_Atlas.textureNamed("text"))
        _Sprites.append(_Atlas.textureNamed("text"))
        _Sprites.append(_Atlas.textureNamed("text"))
        _Sprites.append(_Atlas.textureNamed("text"))
        ...
```

after these lines of code, all of them have the same error: *Cannot convert value of type 'SKTexture' to expected argument type 'Int'*

I don't know why, because it obviously wants a string(for the name of the sprite), and also, when i try this:

```swift
        _Sprites.append(_Atlas.textureNamed(Int("text")))
        ...
```

It gives me this error: *Cannot convert value of type 'Int?' to expected argument type 'String'*
Is there anyone who knows why I have this problem?

Comment: It looked like `_Sprites` is of type `[Int]` and not `[SKTexture]`.

Comment: thank you that solved it. I declared the sprites as Int instead of string. @ George_E

Comment: Ok, I'll add it as an answer for people in the future experiencing similar problems :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `_Sprites` is of type `[Int]` and not `[SKTexture]`. You are trying to append `SKTexture`s, and as the error says:

> Cannot convert value of type 'SKTexture' to expected argument type 'Int'

Meaning that Swift can see that you are trying to set an `SKTexture` where it expects an `Int`.

---

Change your code like so (yours may be slightly different):

```
_Sprites = [Int]()
```

to:

```
_Sprites = [SKTexture]()
```